# Double brace initialization

Tags: c++, initialization, c++14, language-lawyer, default-constructor

Which constructor should be called in the following code and why?

```
struct S
{
    int i;
    S() = default;
    S(void *) : i{1} { ; }
};

S s{{}};
```

If I use `clang` (from trunk), then the second one is called.

If the second constructor is commented out, then `S{{}}` is still valid expression, but (I believe) move-constructor from default-constructed instance of `S{}` is called in the case.

Why conversion constructor has priority over the default one in the very first case?

The intention of such a combination of the constructors of `S` is to save its `std::is_trivially_default_constructible_v< S >` property, except a finite set of cases, when it should be initialized in a certain way.

Comment: "*If the second constructor is commented out, then S{{}} is still valid expression, but (I sure) move-constructor from default-constructed instance of S{} is called in the case.*" No, it aggregate-initializes `S` with a brace-init'd `int`.

Comment: @ildjarn The question is still in force.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If the second constructor is commented out, then S{{}} is still valid expression, but (I sure) move-constructor from default-constructed instance of S{} is called in the case.

Actually, that's not what happens. The ordering in [dcl.init.list] is:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>   — If T is an aggregate class and the initializer list has a single element of type cv U, [...]
>   — Otherwise, if T is a character array and [...]
>   — Otherwise, if T is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.6.1).

Once you remove the `S(void *)` constructor, `S` becomes an aggregate - it has no user-provided constructor. `S() = default` doesn't count as user-provided because reasons. Aggregate initialization from `{}` will end up value-initializing the `i` member.

---

> Why conversion constructor has priority over the default one in the very first case?

With the `void*` remaining, let's keep going down the bullet list:

> — Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements [...]
>   — Otherwise, if T is a specialization of std::initializer_list, [...]
>   — Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated
>   and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7).

[over.match.list] gives us a two-phase overload resolution process:

> — Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.6.4) of the class T and the
>   argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
>   — If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the
>   candidate functions are all the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the elements
>   of the initializer list.
>
> If the initializer list has no elements and T has a default constructor, the first phase is omitted.

`S` doesn't have any initializer list constructors, so we go into the second bullet and enumerate all the constructors with the argument list of `{}`. We have multiple viable constructors:

```
S(S const& );
S(S&& );
S(void *);
```

The conversion sequences are defined in [over.ics.list]:

> Otherwise, if the parameter is a non-aggregate class X and overload resolution per 13.3.1.7 chooses a single
>   best constructor C of X to perform the initialization of an object of type X from the argument initializer list:
>   — If C is not an initializer-list constructor and the initializer list has a single element of type cv U, [...]
>   — Otherwise, the implicit conversion sequence is a **user-defined conversion sequence with the second standard conversion sequence an identity conversion**.

and

> Otherwise, if the parameter type is not a class: [...] — if the initializer list has no elements, **the implicit conversion sequence is the identity conversion**.

That is, the `S(S&& )` and `S(S const& )` constructors are both user-defined conversion sequences plus identity conversion. But `S(void *)` is just an identity conversion.

But, [over.best.ics] has this extra rule:

> However, if the target is
>   — **the first parameter of a constructor** or
>   — the implicit object parameter of a user-defined conversion function
>   and the constructor or user-defined conversion function is a candidate by
>   — 13.3.1.3, when [...]
>   — 13.3.1.4, 13.3.1.5, or 13.3.1.6 (in all cases), or
>   — **the second phase of 13.3.1.7 when the initializer list has exactly one element that is itself an initializer list, and the target is the first parameter of a constructor of class `X`, and the conversion is to `X` or reference to (possibly cv-qualified) `X`**,
>
> **user-defined conversion sequences are not considered.**

This excludes from consideration `S(S const&)` and `S(S&& )` as candidates - they are precisely this case - the target being the first parameter of the constructor as a result of the second phase of [over.match.list] and the target being a reference to possibly cv-qualified `S`, and such a conversion sequence would be user-defined.

Hence, the only remaining candidate is `S(void *)`, so it's trivially the best viable candidate.

Comment: @T.C I guess I wasn't sure if the 2nd one was a standard conversion sequence. The 1st is explicitly stated as user-defined...

Comment: Your analysis is correct except for a little detail: The move and copy constructors are not viable because of 16.3.3.1[over.best.ics]p4 "and the constructor or user-defined conversion function is a candidate by ... the second phase of [over.match.list] when the initializer list has exactly one element that is itself an initializer list, and the target is the first parameter of a constructor of class X, and the conversion is to X or reference to cv X ... user-defined conversion sequences are not considered."

Comment: Had it not been an aggregate when he removed the user-provided constructor (for example by spelling out the definition of the default-constructor), his example with the conversion constructor removed would not compile anymore.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb OMG. There are times when I think I understand C++. And then there are times when I think nobody understands C++. Will change the answer, thanks for pointing it out.