# Why does {} work while () doesn't in initializing an atomic object here?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++14, atomic, list-initialization

Consider the code:

```
#include <atomic>

struct stru {
  int a{};
  int b{};
};

int main() {
  // Doesn't work: std::atomic<stru> as({});
  std::atomic<stru> as{{}};
}
```

The error message produced for direct initialization is like:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:9:26: error: call of overloaded 'atomic(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous
   std::atomic<stru> as({});
                          ^
In file included from prog.cc:1:0:
/opt/wandbox/gcc-7.2.0/include/c++/7.2.0/atomic:200:17: note: candidate: constexpr std::atomic<_Tp>::atomic(_Tp) [with _Tp = stru]
       constexpr atomic(_Tp __i) noexcept : _M_i(__i) { }
                 ^~~~~~
/opt/wandbox/gcc-7.2.0/include/c++/7.2.0/atomic:196:7: note: candidate: std::atomic<_Tp>::atomic(const std::atomic<_Tp>&) [with _Tp = stru] <deleted>
       atomic(const atomic&) = delete;
   ^~~~~~
```

I think the two forms should be no different in this particular case. Why is this happening?

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586836/double-brace-initialization

Comment: @StoryTeller: Yes, [Direct list initialization compiles successfully, but normal direct initialization fails, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469979/direct-list-initialization-compiles-successfully-but-normal-direct-initializati) is the duplicate.

Comment: @DavisHerring - Thanks for pinging me. I didn't wanna hammer it closed the other day, since I wasn't 100% sure.